# Click few times on button makes the page is blocked

Tags: javascript

When You click on button, page should scroll down, to div with id="myTarget".

here is my HTML:

```
<button class="go"> GO </button>
<div id="myTarget">
   <p>
        la lalal lalala lalala 
    </p>
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $(".go").on('click', function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
    $('html, body').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $("#myTarget").offset().top  }, 3000);
 });
});
```

My problem is that when you click a **few times** on button, page scroll down. After that you can't scroll up. Is any way to stop click event while page moving?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvjLcr56/)

Comment: how many times is "**a few times**" - I got bored after 20 and it still worked as advertised

Comment: few times is few times ;)  (3,5,8). But I think you don't understand me :D
1) click 5 times in button "GO" (fast);
2) Wait until page is scrolled down ;
3) Try to scroll to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you stop the animation when user mousewheel?

```
$(function() {
      $(".go").on('click', function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
        $('html, body').animate({ 
            scrollTop: $("#myTarget").offset().top  }, 3000);
     });

});
var page = $("html, body");
page.on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
       page.stop();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/krbuod56/)

Answer (score 0):

What about disabling the button while it is running and enabling it again once animation is done?

```
$(function() {
  $(".go").on('click', function(event) {
     var $but = jQuery(this);
     event.stopPropagation();
     $but.attr("disabled", true);
    $('html, body').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $("#myTarget").offset().top  }, 3000, "linear", function(){
           $but.removeAttr("disabled");
        });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your animation is getting appended onto the previous animation for the html and body tags. Thus, you have to wait for all of the animations that have been started to die before you can scroll back up.

Things that you can do about this problem

1. Make the duration of the animation smaller
2. Call `stop()` on the elements you are animating before creating the new animation
3. Call `stop()` if the window is scrolled. This solution could be problematic if you ever have the body tag doing other animations. The first two solutions should be enough, anyway.

The first should be self explanatory and the second is very easy:

```
$(".go").on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('body').stop().animate({ 
        scrollTop: $("#myTarget").offset().top  }, 500);
});
```

You also only need to animate the body element (not the html element).

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rvjLcr56/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that if you rapidly click the button a couple of times it'll scroll down and not let you scroll back up, and not that it doesn't work when you "Click Button, Scroll Down, wait, Scroll Up".

If it's the first case, you can fix it like this.

```
 $(function() {       $(".go").on('click', function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
           $(".go").attr("disabled", true).delay(3000).attr("disabled", false);         $('html, body').animate({ 
             scrollTop: $("#myTarget").offset().top  
}, 
3000);   
});      
});
```

This means that when you click on the button, it will be disabled for 3000 milliseconds (the time of your animation. This should stop a user from being able to click on it and trigger the animation more than once while it's animating.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scrolling state, like so :

```
$(function() {
    //global var
    isScrolling = false;

    $(".go").on('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if(!isScrolling) {
            isScrolling = true;

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#myTarget").offset().top  }, 3000,
                //Only when it's completed (callback)
                function() {
                    isScrolling = false;
                }
            );
        }   
    });
});
```

Your problem is that it keeps trying to scroll down even though you are already down.